# issue passing data to segue.destination within function

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, segue

I'm trying to make 2 API calls on Segue invoke and ultimately pass Array of Data from Second Call to `CollectionView`. With first call I'm getting one value **`catID`**, which I need in order to make the other call:

```
let searchEndpoint: String = MY_ENDPOINT

// Add auth key
let serviceCallWithParams = searchEndpoint + "?PARAMETER"
guard let url = URL(string: serviceCallWithParams) else {
    print("Error: cannot create URL")
    return
}

let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

// setting up the session
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

// making the request
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
    (data, response, error) in
    // error check
    guard error == nil else {
        print("error")
        print(error)
        return
    }
    // make sure we got data
    guard let responseData = data else {
        print("Error: did not receive data")
        return
    }
    // parse JSON
    do {
        guard let catData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            print("error converting data to JSON")
            return
        }
        if let data = catData["data"] as? [String: Any] {
            if let array = data["categories"] as? [Any] {
                if let firstObject = array.first as? [String: Any] {
                    if let catId = firstObject["catId"] as? Int {
                        getTitles(catId: catId)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch  {
        print("error converting data to JSON")
        return
    }
}
task.resume()
```

**And then getTitles function looks like this:**

```
func getTitles(catId: Int) {
    let catIdString = String(catId)
    let titlesEndPoint: String = MY_ENDPOINT + catIdString
    // Add auth key
    let titlesEndPointWithParams = titlesEndPoint + "?PARAMETER"
    guard let titlesUrl = URL(string: titlesEndPointWithParams) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }

    let titlesUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: titlesUrl)

    // set up the session
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: titlesUrlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        // check for any errors
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling GET on listCategoryTitles")
            print(error)
            return
        }
        // make sure we got data
        guard let titlesData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        // parse the JSON
        do {
            guard let allTitles = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: titlesData, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                print("error converting data to JSON")
                return
            }
            if let titlesJson = allTitles["data"] as? [String: Any] {
                if let titlesArray = titlesJson["titles"] as? Array<AnyObject> {
                    self.books = []
                    for (index, value) in titlesArray.enumerated() {
                        var book = Book()
                        book.bookTitle = value["title"] as? String
                        book.bookAuthor = value["author"] as? String
                        if let imageSource = value["_links"] as? Array<AnyObject> {
                            book.bookImageSource = imageSource[1]["href"] as? String
                        }
                        self.books?.append(book)
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch  {
            print("error converting data to JSON")
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**Now when I put:**

```
let resultsVC = segue.destination as? CollectionViewController
resultsVC?.books = self.books
```

outside function, in target controller I'm getting an empty array as output on first click, but on every next one I'm getting proper data.
When I try putting this inside function ***"getTitles"*** the output in CollectionViewController is ***"nil"*** every time.
Worth mentioning could be that I have ***"books"*** variable defined like so:

**Main Controller:**

```
var books: [Book]? = []
```

**Collection Controller:**

```
var books: [Book]?
```

and I have created type [Book] which is basically object with 3 string variables in separate struct.

**All of the code above is encapsulated in**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowResults" {
```

Any help/guideline would be much appreciated!

Comment: when you write self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowResults", sender: nil)  ?? add the code of call Segue.

Comment: Your API calls will complete asynchronously, so you need to perform your segue from the completion closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make api call it will execute in background means `asynchronously` where as `prepare(for:sender:)` will call `synchronously`.

Now from your question it is looks like that you have create segue in storyboard from `Button` to `ViewController`, so before you get response from your api you are moved to your destination controller, to solved your issue you need to create segue from your `Source` ViewController to `Destination` ViewController and set its identifier. After that inside `getTitles(catId: Int)` method after your for loop perform segue on the main thread.

```
for (index, value) in titlesArray.enumerated() {
    var book = Book()
    book.bookTitle = value["title"] as? String
    book.bookAuthor = value["author"] as? String
    if let imageSource = value["_links"] as? Array<AnyObject> {
        book.bookImageSource = imageSource[1]["href"] as? String
    }
    self.books?.append(book)
}

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowResults", sender: nil)
}
```

After that inside your `prepare(for:sender:)` make changes like below.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if segue.identifier == "ShowResults" {
          let resultsVC = segue.destination as? CollectionViewController
          resultsVC?.books = self.books
     }
}
```